# How to set a param in laravel dusk "attach" method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

My app has 3 input forms for image attachment. Additionary, these 3 forms do not set ids, class name...

In this situation, how do I set a first param in "attach" method.

When I try below, it retreives first input.

attach->("input", filepath)

```
<body class="">
<span id="react-root">
    <section class="_sq4bv _29u45"><main class="_8fi2q  _4kfp8" role="main">
    <article class="_mesn5">
    <header class=" _3fdmx">
        <div class="_b0acm">
            <div class="_qdmzb">
                <div class="_62ai2">
                    <button class="_3xjwv " title="Add a profile photo">
                        <img alt="Add a profile photo" class="_cuacn" src="https://yhsckab.jpg">
                    </button>
                    <div>
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" class="_l8al6">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <section class="_o6mpc"></section>
    </header>
<div class="_tb97a">
    <h1 class="_kc4z2">test</h1> </div>
</article>
</main>
<nav class="_68u16  _evlcw " role="navigation">
    <div class="_s4gw0 _bz8nr ">
        <div class="">
            <div class="_k3nd9"></div>
            <div class="_4pxed">
            </div>
            <form class="_7xah4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" class="_l8al6">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</section>
</span>
<noscript>
</noscript>
<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset">
</div>
<div class="_ip5r5 _c2vev">
    <div class="_162ov "></div>
</div>
<div>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" class="_l8al6">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do they have `name` attributes?

Comment: yes, all of them have the same name "file".

Comment: Can you post the (smallest possible) HTML code that contains all three inputs?

Comment: ```<form class="bik6s0s" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" class="sbjah6s"></form>```

Comment: Do you have three forms with one input each? Or one form with three inputs?

Comment: Please refer to the code I've added ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors to differentiate them:

```
$browser->attach('header input', $filepath);
$browser->attach('nav input', $filepath);
$browser->attach('._ip5r5._c2vev + div input', $filepath);
```